# Hide row when checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi guys hope you are doing well.Actually I want to hide a row when the checkbox within the row is checked and my codes are not working. Help please!Thanks

MY HTML CODE:

```
<table id="test">
<tr>
<td><label value="name">Name</input><br><input type='text'></input></td>
<td><label value="name">LastName</input><br><input type='text'></input></td>
<td><input type='checkbox'></input></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label value="name">Name</input><br><input type='text'></input></td>
<td><label value="name">LastName</input><br><input type='text'></input></td>
<td><input type='checkbox'></input></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label value="name">Name</input><br><input type='text'></input></td>
<td><label value="name">LastName</input><br><input type='text'></input></td>
<td><input type='checkbox'></input></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
```

MY JS CODE:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('input[type=checkbox]').(change(),function()
    {
        if (this.checked) 
        {
         $("#test tr").attr("hide", true);
        }   
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: `$(this).closest("tr").hide()`; is all you need!

Comment: `$('input[type=checkbox]').(change(),function()` if you have a named function `change` you dont need an unnamed one you can just have `$('input[type=checkbox]').(change)`

Comment: I have tried using this too.But still it didn't work :/

Comment: The HTML provided in question is not valid. **No closing label tag & unnecessary closing tag**

Comment: I'd suggest you familiarise yourself with both [the docs](http://api.jquery.com) and the browser console.

Answer (score 2):

> Actually I want to hide a row when the checkbox within the row is
>   checked and my codes are not working.

There seems to be multiple issues with your code

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').on("change",function() //change() changed to "change" 
{
    $(this).closest("tr").hide(); //observe changes in this line       
});
```

**Explanation**

- unless `change()` returns `"change"`, your event handler will not be invoked on `change` event
- You don't need to handle `if(this.checked)` since once your checkbox's value is changed, it won't be visible
- Just find the closest `tr` and hide the same. `$("#test tr").attr("hide", true);` will simply add a `hide` attribute to all rows